# pandas.DataFrame.to_excel leaves empty top left cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I combined several pandas Series to a DataFrame and then used to_excel to write it to an existing xlsx file. my problem is, that everytime I try it, the top left cell of the table stays blank. As I save multiple tables within an excel sheet, the description in this cell is important.

The code I used is similar to the following:

```
import pandas as pd

indexes = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
num1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
num2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
num3 = [9, 10, 11, 12]
series1 = pd.Series(data=num1, index=indexes)
series2 = pd.Series(data=num2, index=indexes)
series3 = pd.Series(data=num3, index=indexes)
filename = "test.xlsx"
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'foo': series1,
        'bar': series2,
        'baz': series3,
    }
)
print(df)
df.columns.name = "TITLE"
print(df)
with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, mode="a", engine="openpyxl", if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet", startrow=0, header=True)
```

When I use print, the TITLE is shown on the screen, but it doesn't appear in the excel file.
I would really apppreciate if somebody could explain me what I did wrong....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the `index_label` parameter is for.

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet", startrow=0, header=True, index_label='TITLE')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html